# Gcm phone_registration_error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to set up an application to work with gcm but every time I get the phone_registration_error error 
according to the Gcm documentation this error means:

```
Incorrect phone registration with Google. 
This phone doesn't currently support GCM.
```

But I don't understand why my it's not supported, I tested this on a real android device and a emulator with the google api's

My MainActivity:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    checkNotNull(SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");

    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    Log.i(TAG,  "registration id =====  "+regId);
    if(regId.equals("")){
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);

    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Already Registred");
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
```

And my manifest:

[Manifest on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vqfDYSvC)

Comment: What's the Android version running on the phone?

Comment: try to use app on another device with higher android version and not all the divices support Google Apis. If you run an emulator, just create an android version with google apis emulator and create google account on that emulator. It needed when work with GCM.

Comment: On the real device I run 2.3.4 and the emulator runs 2.2 also the emulator has an google account

Comment: I created a new emulator with version 4.0 and with google api's and now I get the registrationID. So does this mean it will not work on android 2.x ?

Comment: More people (me included) have this problem while testing my app on an Android 2.2 device: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/UKwUPZMSqiM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCM only works on devices that run android 2.2 or newer. Also GCM only works if a google account is installed for the device. This is also the reason google recommend using `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />` in the manifest so you are sure the device has a google account.

Comment: The part about "GCM only works if a google account is installed for the device" is no longer true in recent versions of Android.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and after seraching on the internet for many days I noticed this in the google groups (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cerberus-support-forum/eJxOsYqkTxo)  and tried it and it worked flawlessly for me.

There is something wrong with your Google account. Please try this:

- Go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> All

or

Go to Settings -> Apps-> All  (on newer versions)

- Select "Clear data" for "Google Play services" and "Google services framework"
- Reboot the phone

Then check for the GCM id from your app.

If it still doesn't work then remove all your google accounts from the phone and reboot the phone and add the account again.

It worked for me (after implementing many solutions that I got from searching the internet.)

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

i looked in your manifest and you forgot to pass GooglePlay Services metadata.

1. Verify if you have linked GooglePlay services library to your project
2. Try to add this in your

`<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>`

It works nicely for me.

Then recompile and retry. Hope it helps.