# Got json exception phone registration error

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying ionic push notification, i got device token in browser, but i idid not get device token in my phone.

I got this error

[image]

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cerberus-support-forum/eJxOsYqkTxo), there might be something wrong with your Google account. Try these:

- Go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> All
- Select "Clear data" for "Google Play services" and "Google services framework"
- Temporarily unlink your Google account from the phone
- Reboot the phone
- Re-associate your Google account

Also take note that GCM only works on devices that run android 2.2 or newer. Also GCM only works if a google account is installed for the device. This is the reason Google recommended using `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />` in the manifest so you are sure the device has a google account.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772086/gcm-phone-registration-error).